# E: Type 'wget' is not known on line 1 in source list

Tags: external-hdd, wget, source, plex

Hello most helpful humans. I have read endless other threads on this subject, and typed a myriad of commands in terminal, but have caused myself more trouble than benefit it seems.

The problem is Plex, and its ability to find my external drive. Or that was the problem. Now the problem is that I can't seem to update or install anything.

Full error message is:

```
E: Type 'wget' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver
```

Please could somebody help me sort this out? I'm afraid I'm not much clued up on how to use Ubuntu properly - my usual approach when problems arise is to search online and copy code/follow instructions that someone else has written, which usually does whatever trick I'm hoping it will. I don't care at this point if I get Plex working (though it would be an added bonus for sure), but being able to update the computer again would be nice.

I realise it would be more helpful if this post had more information, but I'm afraid I need help knowing what to type in to get such information!

Thank you in advance for any help.

EDITS:

```
john@john-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver: No such file or directory
```

- I have read the malformed line thread, but I find it really hard to understand a lot of the time. Not sure if it pertains to my issue or not. Sorry.

  `john@john-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
  wget -q https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
  deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main`

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver`

Comment: cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver: No such file or directory

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!!, try to re-download again your Plex package with wget.

Comment: Thank you! Not sure what you mean sorry. How do I download with wget?

Comment: please provide me where you find Plex Package and what the Ubuntu version your have?.

Comment: I have version 18.04. I downloaded Plex from their website and followed the instructions there.

Comment: You have a syntax error with the cat command! `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver`  - without `:`

Comment: I wrote the command right, (without the :), this was the output of that command: 
cat: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver: No such file or directory

Comment: Try `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list`. The `.list` extension is left off by the `apt` error message, which confuses things.

Comment: `john@john-Inspiron-15-3552:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list wget -q https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key -O - | sudo apt-key add - deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main`

Comment: What is the correct way for me to post these outputs?!

Comment: @JohnLumley Paste them into the question. Anyway the contents of the `.list` file are plain commands that you should have executed, not put into the `.list` file.

Comment: Jost is right, remove the contents of the `.list` and move to as command lines

Comment: Thank you both. But I don't understand what you mean? Remove the contents? How? Sorry...feeling very stupid...

Comment: Oh...I understand, I think. I pasted from "wget" to "-O -" and got a "Begin PGP Public key block" whole bunch of letters, and an "End Public Key block". So I then pasted the rest of it, put in my password, and nothing at all has happened yet

Comment: after your get the key of Plex, update your apt and install it `sudo apt update && sudo apt install plexmediaserver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the OP's situations :

remove the list first to follow

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/source.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
```

and add a key of Plex Package

```
wget -q https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

and make a list of Plex Package

```
echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
```

and then update your apt and install the Plex Package

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install plexmediaserver
```

**OR**

Try to get Plex Package with repository way.

```
curl https://downloads.plex.tv/plex-keys/PlexSign.key | sudo apt-key add -
echo deb https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/plexmediaserver.list
```

install Plex Package

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install plexmediaserver
```

and verify your installation

```
sudo systemctl status plexmediaserver
```

then config your firewall to allow traffic on Plex

```
sudo nano /etc/ufw/applications.d/plexmediaserver
```

and add

```
[plexmediaserver]
title=Plex Media Server (Standard)
description=The Plex Media Server
ports=32400/tcp|3005/tcp|5353/udp|8324/tcp|32410:32414/udp

[plexmediaserver-dlna]
title=Plex Media Server (DLNA)
description=The Plex Media Server (additional DLNA capability only)
ports=1900/udp|32469/tcp

[plexmediaserver-all]
title=Plex Media Server (Standard + DLNA)
description=The Plex Media Server (with additional DLNA capability)
ports=32400/tcp|3005/tcp|5353/udp|8324/tcp|32410:32414/udp|1900/udp|32469/tcp
```

saved and update your profile list

```
sudo ufw app update plexmediaserver
```

and then allow your firewall rule

```
sudo ufw allow plexmediaserver-all
```

verify your firewall rule

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

and then make the directories that will store data of Plex

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/plexmedia/{movies,series}
sudo chown -R plex: /opt/plexmedia
```

so we can proceed it with server configuration and open your browser with type

```
http://YOUR_SERVER_IP:32400/web
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to be allowing my computer to update as normal now, and no system error messages have been received as per the last few days. Still can't access my hdd through plex, but will keep searching the forum before I ask any more questions. Thank you and @Jos again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a preliminary answer because comments are not sufficient to clear up the OP's situation.

The contents of the file `plexmediaserver.list` should look like:

`deb http://download-address/`

Meaning: the contents of the package `plexmediaserver` can be downloaded as a `deb` file. In your case however, the file contains commands that (probably) should have been executed once. (They involve downloading the public key to the software and adding it to your ring of trusted keys.) Not seeing a line like the above, the `apt` process complains about the `.list` file being malformed.

Re-read the instructions carefully, or provide us with the link, to see where exactly you have gone wrong.